# My buttons are randomly spacing in tkinter after i add a button and text below it

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, tkinter

Okay so, what im wondering is how come all the buttons in the first row (A1,B1,C1 ETC) are spacing the rest of the row away from both sides. Also, how would i fix my code where if the checkbox is ticked it changes the background colour of a button to black, and when it gets unticked it goes back to the default colour?

heres my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk



def home():
        home=tk.Tk()

        home.title("Home Page")
        home.geometry("500x500")
        home.configure(bg="#FFFFFF")

        book_button = tk.Button(home, text="Book Seats", command=movie1)
        book_button.pack()


global movies
movies = [
"Movie 1",
"Movie 2",
"Movie 3"
]


#Add On Button Click Functionality
def onButtonClicked(movie1):
        print("hi")




def movie1():
        movie1 = tk.Tk()
        
        #Set Window
        movie1.title("MOVIE THEATRE SEAT PICKER")
        movie1.geometry("560x850")
        movie1.configure(bg='#FFFFFF')

        clicked = StringVar()
        clicked.set( "Movie 1" )

        #Add Dropdown Menu for movie selection
        #movie_selection = OptionMenu(movie1, clicked, *movies )
        #movie_selection.grid(row=30, column=0, columnspan=425)


        social_var = tk.IntVar()
  
        def social_delete():
          isChecked = social_var.get()
                
          if isChecked == 1:
                  A_2.config(bg="#000000")
                  A_4.config(bg="#000000")
                  A_6.config(bg="#000000")
                  A_8.config(bg="#000000")
                  B_2.config(bg="#000000")
                  B_4.config(bg="#000000")
                  B_6.config(bg="#000000")
                  B_8.config(bg="#000000")
                  C_2.config(bg="#000000")
                  C_4.config(bg="#000000")
                  C_6.config(bg="#000000")
                  C_8.config(bg="#000000")
                  D_2.config(bg="#000000")
                  D_4.config(bg="#000000")
                  D_6.config(bg="#000000")
                  D_8.config(bg="#000000")
                  E_2.config(bg="#000000")
                  E_4.config(bg="#000000")
                  E_6.config(bg="#000000")
                  E_8.config(bg="#000000")
  

          elif isChecked == False:
                  A_2.config(bg="#808080")
                  A_4.config(bg="#808080")
                  A_6.config(bg="#808080")
                  A_8.config(bg="#808080")
                  B_2.config(bg="#808080")
                  B_4.config(bg="#808080")
                  B_6.config(bg="#808080")
                  B_8.config(bg="#808080")
                  C_2.config(bg="#808080")
                  C_4.config(bg="#808080")
                  C_6.config(bg="#808080")
                  C_8.config(bg="#808080")
                  D_2.config(bg="#808080")
                  D_4.config(bg="#808080")
                  D_6.config(bg="#808080")
                  D_8.config(bg="#808080")
                  E_2.config(bg="#808080")
                  E_4.config(bg="#808080")
                  E_6.config(bg="#808080")
                  E_8.config(bg="#808080")

        #Add Social Distancing Check Box

        social_checkbox = tk.Checkbutton(movie1, text="Social Distancing", font=("Arial", 16), variable=social_var, command=social_delete)
        social_checkbox.grid(row=20, column=0, columnspan = 10,padx=0, pady=10)
                        
                        
        #Create 'front' text at front of theatre
        front_text = tk.Label(movie1, text="FRONT - CINEMA SCREEN", bg="#00FF00", font=("Arial", 22, "bold"))
        front_text.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1000, rowspan = 3, padx=130, pady=0)

        #Create guidance text
     
        black_button = tk.Button(movie1, text="",height=1,width=4, bg="#000000", state=DISABLED)
        black_text = tk.Label(movie1, text=" = UNAVAILABLE SEAT")

        green_button = tk.Button(movie1, text="",height=1,width=4, bg="#00FF00", state=DISABLED)
        green_text = tk.Label(movie1, text=" = AVAILABLE SEAT")

        blue_button = tk.Button(movie1, text="",height=1,width=4, bg="#0000FF", state=DISABLED)
        blue_text = tk.Label(movie1, text=" = DISABILITY SEAT")

        black_button.grid(row=11, column=0, pady=10, padx=0)
        black_text.grid(row=11, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)
        green_button.grid(row=12, column=0, pady=10, padx=0)
        green_text.grid(row=12, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)
        blue_button.grid(row=13, column=0, pady=10, padx=0)
        blue_text.grid(row=13, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)
        
        #Create Buttons/Seats
        row_a = tk.Label(movie1, text="A", bg='#ffffff', font=("Arial", 15, "bold"))                    
        A_1 = tk.Button(movie1, text="A1", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        A_2 = tk.Button(movie1, text="A2", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        A_3 = tk.Button(movie1, text="A3", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        A_4 = tk.Button(movie1, text="A4", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        A_5 = tk.Button(movie1, text="A5", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        A_6 = tk.Button(movie1, text="A6", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        A_7 = tk.Button(movie1, text="A7", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        A_8 = tk.Button(movie1, text="A8", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        
        row_b = tk.Label(movie1, text="B", bg='#ffffff', font=("Arial", 15, "bold"))
        B_1 = tk.Button(movie1, text="B1", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        B_2 = tk.Button(movie1, text="B2", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        B_3 = tk.Button(movie1, text="B3", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        B_4 = tk.Button(movie1, text="B4", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        B_5 = tk.Button(movie1, text="B5", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        B_6 = tk.Button(movie1, text="B6", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        B_7 = tk.Button(movie1, text="B7", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        B_8 = tk.Button(movie1, text="B8", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        
        row_c = tk.Label(movie1, text="C", bg='#ffffff', font=("Arial", 15, "bold"))
        C_1 = tk.Button(movie1, text="C1", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        C_2 = tk.Button(movie1, text="C2", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        C_3 = tk.Button(movie1, text="C3", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        C_4 = tk.Button(movie1, text="C4", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        C_5 = tk.Button(movie1, text="C5", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        C_6 = tk.Button(movie1, text="C6", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        C_7 = tk.Button(movie1, text="C7", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        C_8 = tk.Button(movie1, text="C8", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        
        row_d = tk.Label(movie1, text="D", bg='#ffffff', font=("Arial", 15, "bold"))
        D_1 = tk.Button(movie1, text="D1", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        D_2 = tk.Button(movie1, text="D2", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        D_3 = tk.Button(movie1, text="D3", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        D_4 = tk.Button(movie1, text="D4", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        D_5 = tk.Button(movie1, text="D5", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        D_6 = tk.Button(movie1, text="D6", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        D_7 = tk.Button(movie1, text="D7", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        D_8 = tk.Button(movie1, text="D8", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')

        row_e = tk.Label(movie1, text="E", bg='#ffffff', font=("Arial", 15, "bold"))
        E_1 = tk.Button(movie1, text="E1", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        E_2 = tk.Button(movie1, text="E2", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        E_3 = tk.Button(movie1, text="E3", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        E_4 = tk.Button(movie1, text="E4", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        E_5 = tk.Button(movie1, text="E5", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        E_6 = tk.Button(movie1, text="E6", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        E_7 = tk.Button(movie1, text="E7", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')
        E_8 = tk.Button(movie1, text="E8", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080')

        #Insert Buttons/Seats
        row_a.grid(row=4, column=0, padx=5,pady=10)
        A_1.grid(row=4, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
        A_2.grid(row=4, column=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        A_3.grid(row=4, column=3, padx=5, pady=10)
        A_4.grid(row=4, column=4, padx=5, pady=10)
        A_5.grid(row=4, column=5, padx=5, pady=10)
        A_6.grid(row=4, column=6, padx=5, pady=10)
        A_7.grid(row=4, column=7, padx=5, pady=10)
        A_8.grid(row=4, column=8, padx=5, pady=10)
        
        row_b.grid(row=5, column=0, padx=5,pady=10)
        B_1.grid(row=5, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
        B_2.grid(row=5, column=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        B_3.grid(row=5, column=3, padx=5, pady=10)
        B_4.grid(row=5, column=4, padx=5, pady=10)
        B_5.grid(row=5, column=5, padx=5, pady=10)
        B_6.grid(row=5, column=6, padx=5, pady=10)
        B_7.grid(row=5, column=7, padx=5, pady=10)
        B_8.grid(row=5, column=8, padx=5, pady=10)
        
        row_c.grid(row=6, column=0, padx=5,pady=10)
        C_1.grid(row=6, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
        C_2.grid(row=6, column=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        C_3.grid(row=6, column=3, padx=5, pady=10)
        C_4.grid(row=6, column=4, padx=5, pady=10)
        C_5.grid(row=6, column=5, padx=5, pady=10)
        C_6.grid(row=6, column=6, padx=5, pady=10)
        C_7.grid(row=6, column=7, padx=5, pady=10)
        C_8.grid(row=6, column=8, padx=5, pady=10)
        
        row_d.grid(row=7, column=0, padx=5,pady=10)
        D_1.grid(row=7, column=1, padx=5, pady=10)
        D_2.grid(row=7, column=2, padx=5, pady=10)
        D_3.grid(row=7, column=3, padx=5, pady=10)
        D_4.grid(row=7, column=4, padx=5, pady=10)
        D_5.grid(row=7, column=5, padx=5, pady=10)
        D_6.grid(row=7, column=6, padx=5, pady=10)
        D_7.grid(row=7, column=7, padx=5, pady=10)
        D_8.grid(row=7, column=8, padx=5, pady=10)

        row_e.grid(row=8, column=0, rowspan=2, padx=5,pady=10)
        E_1.grid(row=8, column=1, rowspan=2,padx=5, pady=10)
        E_2.grid(row=8, column=2, rowspan=2,padx=5, pady=10)
        E_3.grid(row=8, column=3, rowspan=2,padx=5, pady=10)
        E_4.grid(row=8, column=4, rowspan=2,padx=5, pady=10)
        E_5.grid(row=8, column=5, rowspan=2,padx=5, pady=10)
        E_6.grid(row=8, column=6, rowspan=2,padx=5, pady=10)
        E_7.grid(row=8, column=7, rowspan=2,padx=5, pady=10)
        E_8.grid(row=8, column=8, rowspan=2,padx=5, pady=10)
home()
```

My buttons are spaced out when i haven't specified for them to be

Comment: `columnspan=1000` should be `columnspan=10` `row=4` should be `row=1`  same as b, c, d etc

Comment: The labels put in *column 1* has wider width than those buttons above, so *column 1* will be expanded to hold those labels.  You can set `columnspan` option to `.grid(...)` on those labels like what you did on label `front_text`.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to do too much with one grid. The grid wants to stretch the width of the screen, and in order to do that some cells need to be stretched.

It's better to break your page up into sections. Also, you are trying way too hard to make seats. You can do it in a loop almost effortlessly. Even if you could fight your way to the layout that you want, all on one grid, it's not a good design. Are you going to copy/paste your seats for every movie? Turning the seats and legend into a widget means you can easily reuse them, regardless of movie count.

While you are at it, make Movie a widget, too. Then you can just reuse everything.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox, ttk
from functools import partial


class Seats(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        
        self.seats = []
        self.distance = False
        
        #Create Buttons/Seats
        for i,row in enumerate('ABCDE'):
            tk.Label(self, text=row, bg='#ffffff', font=("Arial", 15, "bold")).grid(row=i, column=0, padx=5, pady=10, sticky='nswe')
            for seat in range(1,9):
                self.seats.append(tk.Button(self, text=f"{row}{seat}", height=1, width=4, bg='#808080'))
                self.seats[-1].grid(row=i, column=seat, padx=5, pady=10) 
                
    def social(self):
        self.distance = not self.distance
        for seat in self.seats[1::2]:
            seat['bg']    = ("#808080", "#000000")[self.distance]
            seat['state'] = (tk.NORMAL, tk.DISABLED)[self.distance]
            

class Legend(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        
        #Create guidance text
        tk.Label(self, text=" = UNAVAILABLE SEAT").grid(row=0, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)
        tk.Button(self, text="",height=1,width=4, bg="#000000", state=tk.DISABLED).grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=0)

        tk.Button(self, text="",height=1,width=4, bg="#00FF00", state=tk.DISABLED).grid(row=1, column=0, pady=10, padx=0)
        tk.Label(self, text=" = AVAILABLE SEAT").grid(row=1, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)

        tk.Button(self, text="",height=1,width=4, bg="#0000FF", state=tk.DISABLED).grid(row=2, column=0, pady=10, padx=0)
        tk.Label(self, text=" = DISABILITY SEAT").grid(row=2, column=1, pady=10, padx=0)
    
        
class Movie(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, title, **kwargs):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        
        self.title(f"SEAT PICKER - {title}")
        self.geometry("560x850")
        self.configure(bg='#FFFFFF')
        
        tk.Label(self, text="FRONT - CINEMA SCREEN", bg="#00FF00", font=("Arial", 22, "bold")).grid(row=0, column=0)
 
        (seats := Seats(self)).grid(row=1, column=0)
        
        Legend(self).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='w')
                
        tk.Checkbutton(self, text="Social Distancing", font=("Arial", 16), command=seats.social).grid(row=3, column=0, padx=0, pady=10)
                        

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        
        self.title("Home Page")
        self.geometry("500x500")
        self.configure(bg="#FFFFFF")

        movies = (
            partial(Movie, self, 'Movie 1'),
            partial(Movie, self, 'Movie 2'),
            partial(Movie, self, 'Movie 3'),
        )
        
        tk.Button(self, text="Book Seats", command=movies[0]).pack()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    Main().mainloop()
```